# How do I convert this to an OOP structure?

Tags: function, class, object

Currently, this codepen I forked displays one tv monitor on the webpage as shown below where the channel button allows the user to toggle different gif's. This gif data is stored as an array in the js file. I want to create multiple tv sets, so I am thinking it may be better to create a TV class and instantiate the TV object n-times through a loop. I am new to OOP in a web dev context, so I haven't yet figured out how to rearchitect the code to accomplish this. Since id's only allow for one HTML element, duplicating the chunk of code below would visually create another tv but without any dynamic features. What then becomes of the tv-body display elements? Would they be enveloped with a show() fx nested with the script's TV class? Thank you so much in advance!

[Cropped Output Displayed Here][1]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Vintage Analog TV</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:indexe.partial.html -->
<main>
    <div class="tv-set">
        <div class="tv-body">
            <div class="screen-container">
                <canvas class="static" width="380" height="280"></canvas>
                <img class="displayed" src="" alt="Nothing" width="380" height="280">
                <div class="screen">
                    <div class="screen-frame"></div>
                    <div class="screen-inset"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-badge">
                <div class="logo-text">Bush</div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="screw"></div>
                    <div class="dial">
                        <button class="channel dial-label pristine">Channel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vents">
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                    <div class="vent"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="screw"></div>
                    <div class="dial">
                        <button class="dial-label" disabled>Volume</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="legs">
            <div class="leg"></div>
            <div class="leg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", tv);


// Helper Functions 

//returns tagname 
jQuery.fn.tagName = function () {
    return this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase;
};

// returns nth parent from target element 
$.fn.nthParent = function (n) {
    var p = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p = p.parent();
    return p;
}

phases = [{
        channels: ["red", "blue"]
    },
    {
        channels: ["green", "yellow"]
    },
    {
        channels: ["red", "green"]
    },
    {
        channels: ["blue", "green"]
    }
]

const container = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
const template = document.getElementsByClassName("tv-set")

for (let i = 0; i < phases.length; i++) {
    const clone = template[i].cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute("id", "tv-" + (i + 1))
    console.log("clone id: ", clone.getAttribute("id"))
    clone.setAttribute("data-channel", 0)
    clone.setAttribute("name", "tv-" + i)
    // clone.style.backgroundColor = phases[i].channels[0]
    container.appendChild(clone)
}


function tv() {

    let cnvs = document.querySelectorAll(".static");

    //Gather all static elements 
    // let scrns = $(".static").getContext
    // console.log("Screen 01: ", scrns)

    // var cnv = document.getElementById("static"),
    // var cnv = document.querySelector(".static"), //works in place of line above

    // Need to establish a boolean array for the isStatic 
    let c = []
    let isStatic_arr = []
    // Need to establish a boolean array for the isStatic 



    cnvs.forEach((cnv) => {
        isStatic_arr.push(false)
        var c = cnv.getContext("2d"),
            cw = cnv.offsetWidth,
            ch = cnv.offsetHeight,
            staticScrn = c.createImageData(cw, ch),
            staticFPS = 30,
            // isStatic_arr.push(false),
            // isStatic = false,
            staticTO,
            gifData = [{
                    // file: "https://i.ibb.co/chSK1Zt/willie.gif",
                    file: "./media/back-to-school-chacha.gif",
                    desc: "Stephen Chow Fight Back to School"
                    // <video controls autoplay>
                    // <source src="fbts_chacha_sound.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    // <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    // Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    // </video>
                },
                {
                    file: "https://i.ibb.co/chSK1Zt/willie.gif",
                    desc: "Steamboat Willie (Mickey Mouse) steering a ship"
                },
                {
                    file: "https://i.ibb.co/0FqQVrj/skeletons.gif",
                    desc: "Spooky scary skeletons sending shivers down your spine"
                },
                {
                    file: "https://i.ibb.co/Hpnwgq2/kingkong.gif",
                    desc: "King Kong waving on Empire State Building",
                },
                {
                    file: "https://i.ibb.co/fp0PSjv/tracks.gif",
                    desc: "Looking at train tracks from behind a train",
                },
                {
                    file: "https://i.ibb.co/5FM7BtH/nuke.gif",
                    desc: "Nuclear explosion at sea",
                }
            ],
            gifs = [],
            channel = 0;

        for (g in gifData) {
            gifs.push(new Image());
            gifs[g].src = gifData[g].file;
            gifs[g].alt = gifData[g].desc;
        }



        /* Static */
        var runStatic = function () {
            isStatic = true;
            c.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

            for (var i = 0; i < staticScrn.data.length; i += 4) {
                let shade = 127 + Math.round(Math.random() * 128);
                staticScrn.data[0 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[1 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[2 + i] = shade;
                staticScrn.data[3 + i] = 255;
            }
            c.putImageData(staticScrn, 0, 0);

            staticTO = setTimeout(runStatic, 1e3 / staticFPS);
        };
        runStatic();

        /* Channels */
        var changeChannel = function (button, idx) {
            console.log("Tv-set: ", idx)
            console.log("Tv-set- " + idx + "button: " + button)

            // var displayed = document.getElementById("displayed");
            var displayed = document.querySelectorAll(".displayed")[idx];
            var display_parent = $(".displayed")[1]

            console.log("Display: ", displayed)
            console.log("Display's parent: ", display_parent)


                ++channel;
            if (channel > gifData.length)
                channel = 1;

            // this.classList.remove("pristine");
            button.classList.remove("pristine");

            // this.style.transform = `rotate(${channel * 360/(gifData.length + 1)}deg)`;
            button.style.transform = `rotate(${channel * 360/(gifData.length + 1)}deg)`;

            theCanvas = document.querySelectorAll(".static")[idx]

            // cnv.classList.remove("hide");
            theCanvas.classList.remove("hide");
            displayed.classList.add("hide"); //CAUSING PROBLEMS

            if (!isStatic[idx])
                runStatic();

            setTimeout(function () {
                // cnv.classList.add("hide");
                theCanvas.classList.add("hide");
                displayed.classList.remove("hide");

                displayed.src = gifs[channel - 1].src;
                displayed.alt = gifs[channel - 1].alt;

                isStatic = false;

                clearTimeout(staticTO);
            }, 300);
        };


        function iterate(item, index) {
            console.log(`${item} has index ${index}`);
        }

        // const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("channel dial-label pristine");
        // const btns_arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".channel"))
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".channel")

        buttons.forEach((btn, i) => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => changeChannel(btn, i));
        });


    });

}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INtzP.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOxoQ.png
```

(11/14/20) @ggirodda, thank you so much for the example. Unfortunately, I am still a bit stuck. Why is it when I use `const template = document.getElementsByClassName("tv-body").children[0]`, I get the error:  **script_001.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.tv (script_001.js:154)** Shouldn't the tv-body class have children based on the code snippet below?

(11/14/20) Addressed error above by removing `.children[0]` but unsure as to why that works and why it was undefined.

(11/19/20) Resolved! Sort of, that is. All tv clones can will run as intended, meaning the static display will remain active on all tv's whose channel button has not been pressed, and the channels can be changed independently. Here were the main changes I made on the original code:

1. All id's replaced with classes so that they can be accessed and wrapped the "tv-body" and "legs" in a separate div so that they can be cloned as a set.
2. Gathered all the "tv-set" class elements outside of the tv function() and then performed the setup functions forEach()
3. Converted a few of the variables e.g canvas, isStatic into arrays so that their states and displays could be toggled independently. I am sure there is more work to be done here as some of the variables may still be shared among the clones.

Comment: you don't need to do OOP to achive this. You can do a for loop on each tv item to append the html code dynamically, than use your addEventListener on class elements, not id

Comment: @ggirodda, so create a for-loop with the js script and let tv_set_01 = tv()? Sorry for the stupid question and thanks!

Comment: see the example in the code below

Answer (score 0):

You can take some inspiration from the code below, the example is less complex but the idea is the same

```js
const tvs = [
  { channels: ["red", "blue"] },
  { channels: ["green", "yellow"] }
]

function changeChannel(idx) {
  const tv = tvs[idx]
  const tvNode = document.getElementById("tv-" + idx)
  const currentChannelIdx = parseInt(tvNode.getAttribute("data-channel"))
  const nextChannelIdx = tv.channels[currentChannelIdx + 1] ? currentChannelIdx + 1 : 0;
  tvNode.style.backgroundColor = tv.channels[nextChannelIdx]
  tvNode.setAttribute("data-channel", nextChannelIdx)
}

const container = document.getElementById("container")
const template = document.getElementById("tv-template").children[0]

for (let i = 0; i < tvs.length; i++) {
  const clone = template.cloneNode(true);
  clone.setAttribute("id", "tv-" + i)
  clone.setAttribute("data-channel", 0)
  clone.style.backgroundColor = tvs[i].channels[0]
  container.appendChild(clone)
}

const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("channel-btn")

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => changeChannel(i), false);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="tv-template" style="display: none;">
  <div class="tv" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <button class="channel-btn">next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the first for-loop minus the background color in your code snippet is where I am essentially duplicating the tv display containing all its child elements and then assigning each a unqiue identifier based on the order it was read in from the array of dicts{} above? Thanks again!

Comment: yes, in the first loop a node template is cloned for every item of the array, and appended to container with an id based on its position in the array ('tv-' + `POSITION`), and a `data-channel` equal to 0 by default. The data-channel is actually the index of the current background color, this property will be used to calculate the next background to put on tv element

Comment: Alright, now that I have cloned the displays, I am trying to get the channel button working for each tv. I keep getting undefined for the button item I am passing to to the function. The same "undefined" error is occurring when I try to get tvs.length, so I had to hardcode the number of iterations. I was thinking can I use the tv-id e.g "tv-1" as the name of the button's parent and passing the child element witht name "channel-button" to the changeChannel function? That way, if I were to add a power button as well, the fxn would know which one.

Comment: you can loop over every button parent, than in the loop, find the button child, using `const theButton = currentButtonParent.getElementsByClassName("the-button-class")[0]`, and then `theButton.addEventListener("click" ...)`. You can take the index from the loop over button parent classes, this index will be used to get the current item in tvs array

Comment: Sorry again @ggirodda, but when you say "button parent", does that mean retaining the same syntax `const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("channel-btn")` or is that referring to the <div class="dial"> that wraps around the <button id="channel class="dial-label pristine"> ? Just as before, I am still coming across this undefined error at the line `this.classList.remove("pristine");`, which is the first time within the changeChannel() where the passed in object is actually be manipulated. This is using the same syntax iterating through buttons.length and then buttons[i].addEventList.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Can you update your question with a code snippet ? even if it doesn't work, so I can better understand where the problem is.

Comment: Don't say sorry! I have learned so much from your feedback already!!! The code has been updated. It's functioning, but I will need to refactor it soon so that's it's more versatile when other features are incorporated. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad to have been able to help you. If you think that my answer is the right one, you can put it as the correct one if you want.

Comment: How should I mark it if the answer was a combination of yours and a couple other solutions I found? Thanks!

Comment: in this case you can just mark the answer as useful, by clicking the arrow up on the left of the answer